# Intel TBB and Cilk Plus thread affinity on Intel MIC

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb, xeon-phi, cilk-plus

I would like to write parallel code for Intel Xeon Phi using Intel TBB and Cilk Plus but i have a problem with thread affinity. I want to bind one thread to one logical core. Is is possible to set affinity like in OpenMP? I mean KMP_AFFINITY="compact". Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve if you *must* have fine grain controlled thread affinity. TBB doesn't have proper thread affinity, only task level affinity. `tbb::affinity_partitioner` will already try to preserve cache coherency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and moreover it is recommended in conjunction with affinity_partitioner on Xeon Phi. Please see [the blog](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/10/31/applying-intel-threading-building-blocks-observers-for-thread-affinity-on-intel) for details. Here is a short code snippet to give you idea how does it look like:

```
class pinning_observer: public tbb::task_scheduler_observer {
public:
    pinning_observer();
    /*override*/ void on_scheduler_entry( bool );
    ~pinning_observer();
};

pinning_observer pinner;
pinner.observe( true );
```

There are no any special means for doing so in Cilk Plus.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks. What about affinity in Intel Cilk Plus?